# Is it possible to have 2 kernels running on GPU at same time, and communicating with each other?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu

If I have 2 programs which are related, is it possible for me to have one kernel running on 1 SM , the other kernel running on other SM(or SMs) at same time.Also I need them to be able to communicate with each other via global memory. Is it possible? Could I use cuda stream to achieve this?

Comment: Even if it's possible, is it a good idea? You generally don't want any conditional branching or sleeping or locking inside your kernels, which you'd invariably need if you wanted to communicate directly between kernels.

Comment: The main reason is that I designed some GPU kernel which another GPU program "might" need to use it on the flight

Comment: Furthermore, in the general case, requiring communication between running kernels is akin to requiring an in-kernel global sync, which is fraught with peril and can easily lead to deadlock, unless you're certain that both kernels can launch and meet their respective sync points, within the confines of whatever actual HW GPU device you happen to be running on.

Comment: Well, you can obviously give out device pointers to allocated global memory to multiple kernels. Do you have a way for one kernel to signal another, though? A memory model that describes the ordering semantics of accesses?

Comment: I have not thought of a way of signaling. I am thinking of writing 1s and polling in the global memory.

Comment: My ideal scenario is that one GPU program runs to some point, do a "system call" to the other kernel, that kernel runs and return the data to the first program.

Comment: I have no idea what your actual design is, but I'm reasonably certain that what you have in mind won't work or be useful.

Comment: Your ideal scenario sounds like it might be a better fit for cuda dynamic parallelism, and I have updated my answer with a note about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's theoretically possible, yes.

I think it is prone to trouble, because, not unlike an in-kernel global sync, it depends on both kernels being able to reach their respective sync points.  This usually implies very small kernels where you can guarantee that regardless of the launch order of blocks, you will get to the sync point.

But a simple proof-possible case is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
__device__ volatile unsigned int sem = 0;
__global__ void kernel1(){

  while(sem < 1);
  printf("kernel1 received signal, sending return signal\n");
  sem = 2;
  __threadfence();
}

__global__ void kernel2(){

  printf("kernel2 sending signal\n");
  sem = 1;
  __threadfence();
  while(sem<2);
  printf("kernel2 received signal\n");
}


int main(){

  cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream1);
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream2);
  printf("Launching kernel 1\n");
  kernel1<<<1,1,0,stream1>>>();
  sleep(2);
  printf("Launching kernel 2\n");
  kernel2<<<1,1,0,stream2>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}
```

This needs to be compiled at minimum for a cc2.0 device.

When run, it should give output like this:

```
Launching kernel 1
Launching kernel 2
kernel2 sending signal
kernel1 received signal, sending return signal
kernel2 received signal
```

If you remove the `stream1` and `stream2` identifiers from the kernel launches on the other hand, the program will hang (because the kernels are both launched into the same stream and therefore serialized.)

Again, I don't think it is a good design, but it's possible under some circumstances.

If you are on a cc3.5 or newer GPU, you might want to investigate using [dynamic parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism) instead (launch one kernel from the other).

Comment: Any of the following situation are likely to hang: It is run on windows and the work is not submitted in the same command buffer, it is run on a small GPU (K1), if the first kernel has enough warps to saturate the SM (not the case of the example), if the first kernel has sufficient warps to saturate the warp scheduler, if the two kernels have different SM launch configuration (shared/L1 configuration or kepler shared bank configuration) and the first launches NumSM warps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment. Actually my first kernel will occupy the entire SM. Will it still work if this is the case? I would like the second kernel to run on a different SM

Comment: As long as your GPU has at least 2 SMs in it, and your kernels launch with `<<<1,xxx>>>` config, it should be possible.  But all the other issues that Greg pointed out still need to be considered.